# triple monitors and xinerama = black screen when game starts?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 15.04, games, xinerama

after a fresh clean install of ubuntu (my old install got borked somehow) i cannot for the life of me get my games from steam to play when Xinerama is enabled, it worked with my last ubuntu install with absolutely no issues, now all that happens is every time i start a game all three screens go black and nothing shows except the cursor no sound no visuals nothing , here are my specs:

- Ubuntu 15.04
- Nvidia 970 using the 352.21 driver
- Intel i7 4790k

and here is my config

```
nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 346.59  (buildd@toyol)  Thu Apr  9 09:44:23 UTC 2015

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ RL2455"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 970"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to enable Basemosaic in the Nvidia driver to get all monitors working together, when Xinerama is enabled.

Comment: ok i tried that and i still have the same issue.. is there anything else special i need to do? any other options im overlooking?